# SQL connect by for many rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to generate "connect by" for many rows in table and sum them all.
I have a table

```
person boss
---------------    
person1 NULL
person2 person1
person3 person2
```

And i want to get table

```
boss is_boss_of
---------------
person1 person2
person1 person3
person2 person3
```

I would like to make connect by expression for everyone in table person-boss?
Is there any way to make it?

Saying about sum i thought about something like this

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT person as boss, person as is_boss_of
            FROM table1
            START WITH boss = person1
            CONNECT BY PRIOR Empno = Mgr;
Union
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT person as boss, person as is_boss_of
            FROM table1
            START WITH boss = person2
            CONNECT BY PRIOR Empno = Mgr;
Union
...
and so on
```

Comment: hard to understand what you want.  Do you really mean there to be a row p1 p3 ? are you trying to SUM something?

Comment: What version of Oracle?  11g R2+ supports recursive WITH (now ANSI), but CONNECT BY has been supported since v2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**

After seeing your update, you just need to drop the START WITH.

**End update**

[CONNECT_BY_ROOT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators004.htm#i1035022) is what you're looking for

This statement

```
SELECT distinct RootBoss, Person FROM (
with employee  as 
(
  Select 1 person , null boss from Dual
  UNION Select 2 , 1 from dual
  UNION Select 3 , 2 from dual
)
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT boss RootBoss, person
FROM employee connect_by

  connect by prior person = boss
  ORDER BY person

  ) t
WHERE ROOTBOSS is not null
ORDER BY
RootBoss, Person
```

Outputs

```
ROOTBOSS               PERSON                 
---------------------- ---------------------- 
1                      2                      
1                      3                      
2                      3
```

Adding SUMS and GROUPS is pretty easy