# Oracle SQL "connect by prior" for getting inherited permissions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, hierarchical

I have data like:

```
file_id  |  file_name | user_group_id | group_permission | file_parent
1           abc              devs          read               NULL
1           abc              devs          write              NULL
2           def              NULL          NULL                1
3           jkl              NULL          NULL                2 
3           ghi              end_u         read                2
```

and it is in a sort of hierarchy tree where files has a user group and permission attached,
the data that I have doesn't always have user group and permissions attached, if this is the case then they should inherit the user group and permission of their parent (some times it may be a super parent, i.e., the parent of a parent). I want to build the output like below but I can't use recursion

```
file_id  |  file_name | user_group_id | group_permission | file_parent
    1           abc              devs          read               NULL
    1           abc              devs          write              NULL
    2           def              devs          read                1
    2           def              devs          write               1
    3           jkl              devs          read                2
    3           jkl              devs          write               2
    4           ghi              end_u         read                2
```

I tried to look for a solution and it seems that Oracle has the "connect by prior" structure that can help but I am quite new to database development and don't know how to build this.

I have checked these pages but I can't yet visualize a solution:

- [SQL connect by for many rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890170/sql-connect-by-for-many-rows)
- [Oracle Connect By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848974/oracle-connect-by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT file_id,
       file_name,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT(user_group_id) AS user_group_id,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT(group_permission) AS group_permission,
       file_parent
FROM   table_name
START WITH
       user_group_id    IS NOT NULL
AND    group_permission IS NOT NULL
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR file_id    = file_parent
AND    user_group_id    IS NULL
AND    group_permission IS NULL
ORDER BY
       file_id,
       file_name,
       group_permission
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( file_id, file_name, user_group_id, group_permission, file_parent ) AS
SELECT 1, 'abc', 'devs',  'read',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'abc', 'devs',  'write', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'def', NULL,    NULL,    1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'jkl', NULL,    NULL,    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'ghi', 'end_u', 'read',  2 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | FILE_ID | FILE_NAME | USER_GROUP_ID | GROUP_PERMISSION | FILE_PARENT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | abc | devs | read |  |
> | 1 | abc | devs | write |  |
> | 2 | def | devs | read | 1 |
> | 2 | def | devs | write | 1 |
> | 3 | jkl | devs | read | 2 |
> | 3 | jkl | devs | write | 2 |
> | 4 | ghi | end_u | read | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=80fff1ee4f21523330dc40d0d4685277)*